# Dropdown with Color options and color related text

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I had a requirement like I needs to bind the dropdownlist options having the color in a square(like button) and color's name in option tag. 
Means :
 color -  Color Name

From some of the references, I tried to have the code. But it applied for the back ground. I dont want as background.

```
<body>
<select id="ddlCurriculum" onchange="AssignGrade()"><option value="0">Not Assigned</option>
<option style="background-color:#ff0000" value="1">Advanced</option>
<option style="background-color:#ffff00" value="2">Proficient</option>
<option style="background-color:#0000ff" value="3">Standard</option>
<option style="background-color:#008000" value="4">Emerging</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I needs to get the option as like color and color name.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for a second and found this (it uses Vue.js)

[image: codepen example]
https://codepen.io/nmcinteer/pen/owZoqe

```
<div id="color-picker">
<div class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <span @click="toggleDropdown()" v-html="selector"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown" v-show="active">
        <li v-for="color in colors" @click="setColor(color.hex, color.name)"><span :style="{background: color.hex}"></span> {{color.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
.wrapper-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper-dropdown > span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown > span > span {
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown > span:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: calc(50% + 4px);
    margin-top: -6px;
      border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
      border-color: #2e2e2e transparent;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
      z-index: 10;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid #ababab;
      border-top: 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e2e2e;
      padding: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li > span {
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li:hover {
    background: #eee;
      cursor: pointer;
}

var colors = [
    {
        hex: '#00759A',
      name: 'Blue'
  },
    {
        hex: '#F7941D',
      name: 'Orange'
  },
    {
        hex: '#A71930',
      name: 'Red'
  },
    {
        hex: '#679146',
      name: 'Green'
  }
];


   new Vue({
        el: '#color-picker',
        data: {
            active: false,
            selectedColor: '',
            selectedColorName: '',
            colors: colors
        },
        computed: {
            selector: function() {
                if(!this.selectedColor) {
                    return 'Color';
                }
                else {
                    return '<span style="background: ' + this.selectedColor + '"></span> ' + this.selectedColorName;
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setColor: function(color, colorName) {
                this.selectedColor = color;
                this.selectedColorName = colorName;
                this.active = false;
            },
            toggleDropdown: function() {
                this.active = !this.active;
            },
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any way with Jquery or javascript ? Because we need with select and option tags.